# How Can I display only one column from a styled Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

So I am writing a python program that will pull in data and highlight rows based on a cell value. However, I want to only convert/show one of the highlighted columns(The name of the device) to HTML (and ultimately a pdf) which I can then display to a customer. How could I go about doing this?

Code:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(items)
    
    
 def highlightCritical(s,threshold,column):
    isSDT = pd.Series(data=False, index=s.index)
    isSDT[column] = s.loc[column] > threshold
    return ['background-color: red' if isSDT.any() else '' for v in isSDT]


 def highlightError(s,threshold,column):
     isSDT = pd.Series(data=False, index=s.index)
     isSDT[column] = s.loc[column] > threshold
     return ['background-color: orange' if isSDT.any() else '' for v in isSDT]

 def highlightWarning(s,threshold,column):
     isSDT = pd.Series(data=False, index=s.index)
     isSDT[column] = s.loc[column] > threshold
     return ['background-color: yellow' if isSDT.any() else '' for v in isSDT]




styled_df_a = df.style.apply(highlightWarning, threshold = 0, column = ['warnAlert' , 'confirmedWarnAlert'], axis=1)\
        .apply(highlightError, threshold = 0, column = ['errorAlert' , 'confirmedErrorAlert'],axis=1)\
        .apply(highlightCritical, threshold = 0, column = ['criticalAlert', 'confirmedCriticalAlert'], axis=1)
    


html = styled_df_a.hide_index().render()
with open("html_c.html","w") as fp:
   fp.write(html)
```

Comment: ```styled_df_a['Column Name']``` will return a series of the specified column.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @itprorh66 the styled_df_a is a 'Styler' object. "TypeError: 'Styler' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @itprorh66 I would like to remove/hide all of the other columns so that I am just left with a device name that is either red, orange, or yellow (representing the level of alert the device has)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. For anybody wondering, you can add the style.hide_columns(LIST OF COLUMNS) to the end of your Styler object.

Code:

```
styled_df_a = df.style.apply(highlightWarning, threshold = 0, column = ['warnAlert' , 'confirmedWarnAlert'], axis=1)\
    .apply(highlightError, threshold = 0, column = ['errorAlert' , 'confirmedErrorAlert'],axis=1)\
    .apply(highlightCritical, threshold = 0, column = ['criticalAlert', 'confirmedCriticalAlert'], axis=1)\
    .hide_columns(columnList)
```